# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving an error after this query.

```
                   Select count(*) entity_id
                   FROM pcspro.bas2016_process_and_verify a,
                        pcspro.bas2016_mailout_return b,
                        pcspro.bas2016_universe c
                  WHERE a.entity_id = b.entity_id
                        AND b.entity_id = c.entity_id
                        AND c.entity_id = a.entity_id
               GROUP BY entity_id
               WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL AND ENTITY_REPORTED_STATUS = 'W';
```

Comment: If you are already checking for a.entity_id = b.entity_id and b.entity_id = c.entity_id, why oh why do you need to check for c.entity_id = a.entity_id also? Doesn't it follow automatically from the other two?  Also, better to learn and use the SQL standard syntax for joins: `FROM ... a JOIN ... b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id JOIN ... c ON b.entity_id = c.entity_id WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL`  etc.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a comma and move you're where clause before the group by

```
Select 
    count(*) ,  
    a.entity_id
FROM pcspro.bas2016_process_and_verify a,
    pcspro.bas2016_mailout_return b,
    pcspro.bas2016_universe c
WHERE a.entity_id = b.entity_id
    AND b.entity_id = c.entity_id
    --AND c.entity_id = a.entity_id --no need
AND STATUS IS NOT NULL AND ENTITY_REPORTED_STATUS = 'W' 
GROUP BY a.entity_id
```

Comment: In addition to my comment to the original question, this will still complain about "entity_id" being ambiguous.

Comment: does entity_id exist in any of those tables? if it does exist, does it exist in multiple tables? if so, then use the table alias. for ex) a.entity_id

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit your solution, only you or one of the forum experts can.

Comment: I've updated the code. I was a bit lazy.  Thanks MathGuy.

Answer (score -1):

You should rewrite your query in ANSI SQL:

```
Select count(*),
       entity_id
FROM pcspro.bas2016_process_and_verify a
   INNER JOIN pcspro.bas2016_mailout_return b
      USING(entity_id)
   INNER JOIN pcspro.bas2016_universe c
      USING(entity_id)
WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL
  AND ENTITY_REPORTED_STATUS = 'W'
GROUP BY entity_id;
```